# How to Summarize Consecutive Rows in a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So I have a table that tracks the movements of multiple users inside a building. The columns show the user's ID, what room they are in, and the timestamp in which they were found in that room. The table looks like the following:

```
user_id  location  time                
-------  --------  -------------------   
1        room1     2018-05-18 03:20:00     
1        room1     2018-05-18 03:21:15
1        room2     2018-05-18 03:22:07
2        room1     2018-05-18 03:24:20     
2        room1     2018-05-18 03:27:55
2        room1     2018-05-18 03:29:09      
1        room2     2018-05-18 03:32:37    
1        room1     2018-05-18 03:34:41
1        room1     2018-05-18 03:39:28
```

What I'm trying to do is to summarize the information of how long was each user in each room, like so:

```
user_id  location  duration(s)
-------  --------  -----------
1        room1     75
2        room1     289
1        room2     630
1        room1     287
```

Is there any way to do this with a single query?

Comment: This looks like a gaps and islands problem, tough to handle in MySQL.  But maybe someone will be able to give you a query.

Comment: I think there is a mistake on the last record of the sample input data. Shouldn't  `time`  be equal to `2018-05-18 03:39:28`?

Answer (score 4):

You can handle this using variables or a correlated subquery.  Variables are usually more efficient:

```
select user_id, location, min(time), max(time),
       timestampdiff(second, min(time), max(time)) as duration
from (select t.*,
             (@grp := if(@ul = concat_ws(':', user_id, location), @grp,
                         if(@ul := concat_ws(':', user_id, location), @grp + 1, @grp + 1)
                        )
             ) as grp
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by user_id, time
           ) t cross join
           (select @ul := '', @grp := 0) params
     ) t
group by user_id, location, grp;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63472/1) is a SQL Fiddle with the working code.

Comment: Did you write it just now?))

Comment: i believe `concat(':', user_id, location)` should have been `concat_ws(':', user_id, location)` instead? Also it should not matter because`concat(':', user_id, location)` should also work fine within this query.

Comment: This looked so interesting, I'd thought I'd see how it works. I've created the sample dataset as above. However, the query generates visits of 75 and 289 in agreement with the desired output, but includes one of 18316513 from 2017-10-18 03:39:28 to 2018-05-18 03:34:41, ignoring the more obvious end time of 2018-05-18 03:20:00. It also creates zero-length visits for user 1 and room2 at 2018-05-18 03:22:07 and 2018-05-18 03:32:37. It omits the last two in the desired output as well. Just don't ask me why!

Comment: @Nick The error seems to be in the sample data, not in the query. I tested Gordon's query and it produces identical results to my query.

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Gordon Linoff after trying this out on my database with the same dataset, I found that it failed to properly reproduce the output for the duration of user 1 in room2, instead producing 2 zero-length visits, as Nick previously stated. After some inspection it seems that the query only correctly outputs the result when the rows being queried are consecutive. After deleting the 3 rows in between the 2 rows of room2 inputs, the query outputs the desired result of 630. Is there any way to make this properly output the 630 even when the rows aren't consecutive? Thank you very much!

Comment: @FirmanR . . . The inner-most query orders by `user_id` and `time`.  The rows do not have to be "consecutive" in the original data.   The query uses the data to determine the ordering.  It works fine in SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

*In case you are using MySQL 8.0* you can easily solve this using window functions:

```
;WITH GroupedTable AS (
   SELECT user_id, location, time,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time) - 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, location ORDER BY time) AS grp
   FROM mytable
)
SELECT user_id, location, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, MIN(time), MAX(time)) AS duration
FROM GroupedTable  
GROUP BY user_id, location, grp
```